# gdalwarp not clipping neatline properly

Tags: gdal, pdf, gdalwarp

I have a [PDF file](http://files.ozrunways.com/email_images/I5601_GeoPDF.pdf) (10mb) which contains a NEATLINE polygon in metadata.

```
$ gdalinfo I5601_GeoPDF.pdf
```

> Driver: PDF/Geospatial PDF Files: I5601_GeoPDF.pdf Size is 5906, 3543
>   Coordinate System is: PROJCS["UTM Zone 56, Southern Hemisphere",
>       GEOGCS["GDA94", ... GeoTransform =
>     128363.7573358897, 42.324133621968, 0.8865642156959999
>     6471730.899290663, 0.8865642156959999, -42.324133621968 Metadata:   CREATION_DATE=D:20080515105609+10   CREATOR=BAE SYSTEMS MapMaker.exe
>   2.9.830.19227   **NEATLINE=POLYGON ((191125.203093351592543 6340529.201165121048689,188350.332458852295531 6473000.141725543886423,378308.662319099530578 6476979.201503321528435,381083.532953590154648 6344508.260942890308797,191125.203093351592543 6340529.201165121048689))** ...

Now if I extract the NEATLINE data into a .cvs and use gdalwarp to cut it:

```
$ for i in *.pdf; do gdalinfo $i|grep NEATLINE | awk -F= '{print "id,WKT\n1,\"" $2 "\""}' > $i.csv; gdalwarp -crop_to_cutline -cutline $i.csv -overwrite $i $i.tif; done
```

I get a geotiff that isn't clipped correctly:
[picture of results](http://files.ozrunways.com/email_images/geotif.png)

I've tried this on US 250k maps and it works. I'm wondering whether anybody can tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or is the metadata in the PDF wrong ?

Comment: You can quickly check the validity of the neatline metadata by creating a polygon with those coordinates and overlaying it with your pdf. If using QGIS, you can use the QuickQKT plugin to paste the wkt value and create a polygon layer.

Comment: The neatline does not need to cover exactly the map area.  Overlaying the neatline with QGIS is good idea, and you can also measure a good cutline for gdalwarp QGIS.